# Millions of JDBC SQL Server Table Rows to CSV with Python?

Tags: python, sql, database, csv

So I am having some performance issues with my program. When I run it, it crashes nearly every time. Most likely, the program cannot process over a million rows at once. This occurs when I run `cursor.fetchall()` in the code below:

```
def fill_csv_file(cursor, name):
    """
    Fills a csv file with data based on the given SQL table name
    """
    try:
        use_dataset = "USE canvas"
        select_table = "SELECT * FROM " + name

        cursor.execute(use_dataset)
        cursor.execute(select_table)

        LOG.info("Fetching all rows...")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        LOG.info("Mapping " + str(len(rows)) + " SQL rows onto CSV")
        if rows:
            result = list()
            column_names = list()
            for i in cursor.description:
                column_name = i[0]
                column_names.append(column_name)

            result.append(column_names)
            for row in rows:
                result.append(row)

            with open(csv_file_path, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
                csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
                for row in result:
                    csvwriter.writerow(row)
            LOG.info("SQL mapped onto CSV for table name " + name)
        else:
            LOG.info("No rows found for query: {}".format(select_table))
            return
    except Exception as e:
        LOG.error(e)
```

Are there any alternative methods to using `cursor.fetchall()`? I tried changing the `cursor.arraysize` to 5000, but there were still memory issues.

I also tried something like this, with OUTFILE

```
def fill_csv_file(cursor, name):
    """
    Fills a csv file with data based on the SQL table needed
    """
    try:
        LOG.info("Filling CSV with SQL data for " + name + "...")

        use_dataset = "USE canvas"
        outfile = 'SELECT * INTO OUTFILE "' + csv_file_path + '" FROM ' + name +";"
        print(outfile)
        cursor.execute(use_dataset)
        cursor.execute(outfile)

        LOG.info("Done")
    except Exception as e:
        LOG.error(e)
```

But I don't use MYSQL, so this will not work.

The reason why I'm not doing this manually is because there are dozens upon dozens of SQL tables I am trying to translate, and the project I'm using requires Python to automate this project. Any advice would come in handy!

**EDIT some more code:**

```
def connect_db():
    """
    Connects to the SQL Server database using JayDeBeAPI
    """
    try:
        LOG.info("Connecting to database...")
        driver_name = creds.driver_jdbc
        connection_url = creds.db_server_url
        connection_properties = {
            "user": creds.uuid,
            "password": creds.password,
        }
        jar_path = r"C:\Users\Sabri\Documents\GitHub\csv_to_redivis\jtds-1.3.1.jar"

        connection = jaydebeapi.connect(
            driver_name, connection_url, connection_properties, jar_path)
        LOG.info("Connection to DB " + driver_name +
                 " of connection " + connection_url + " successful.")

        return connection

    except Exception as e:
        LOG.error(e)

def one_csv():
    try:
        connection = connect_db()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.arraysize = 5000
        fill_csv_file(cursor, 'assignment_group_score_dim')
    except Exception as e:
        LOG.error(e)
```

Comment: what library are you using to create `cursor`

Comment: Oh my bad, I am using jaydebeapi.

Comment: can you not use a specific library for your database? this library is not great because it has to serialize and deserialize data through the JVM which is extra overhead and it doesn't even seem to have an iteration protocol for the `cursor`

Comment: what do you mean by not use a specific library?

Comment: what database are you using? there is probably a specific library for it, not a generalized one such as `jaydebeapi`

Comment: I am using SQL Server (jTDS) if that helps

Comment: I will look into that @ChrisCharley

Comment: conversely you can run `cursor.fetchone()` in a `while` loop and check to see if it is `None`. once it becomes `None` you know you have exhausted the result set although this will take a long time because you will have to deserialize every row through the JVM in to a Python object

Comment: @gold_cy You have been such a great help. Thank you!! But yeah, I think I will look into other libraries. This is simply the one that worked for me initially.

Comment: I can post an example of how to do it with this one but it will be slow, I think the official client for SQL Server is `pyodbc`

Comment: I would like to mark you with the correct answer, sure. Also, yes I used pyodbc before but  I didnt find any information regarding jdbc. I will probably revert back to it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per our discussion, slightly modifying the code to use `cursor.fetchone()` over `cursor.fetchall()` will prevent your program from crashing but it will be slow as mentioned due to deserialization through the JVM.

```
def fill_csv_file(cursor, name):
    """
    Fills a csv file with data based on the given SQL table name
    """
    try:
        use_dataset = "USE canvas"
        select_table = "SELECT * FROM " + name

        cursor.execute(use_dataset)
        cursor.execute(select_table)

        LOG.info("Fetching a single row...")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        LOG.info("Mapping SQL rows onto CSV")
        if row:
            column_names = []
            for i in cursor.description:
                column_name = i[0]
                column_names.append(column_name)

        else:
            LOG.info("No rows found for query: {}".format(select_table))
            return

        with open(csv_file_path, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
            csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
            csvwriter.writerow(column_names)
            while row is not None:
                csvwriter.writerow(row)
                row = cursor.fetchone()
        LOG.info("SQL mapped onto CSV for table name " + name)
    except Exception as e:
        LOG.error(e)
```